# How I can transform the result of node.js to prevent ember.js error: No model was found for '0 '?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, coffeescript

Node.js returns (results):

```
[
 {
  "value1": "234",
  "id": 67,
  "value2": "76543"
 },
 {
  "value1": "468",
  "id": 68,
  "value2": "98765"
 },
 {..}
]
```

But Ember.js needs

```
{ "data":[
        {
         "value1": "234",
         "id": 67,
         "value2": "76543"
        },
        {
         "value1": "468",
         "id": 68,
         "value2": "98765"
        },
        {..}
       ]
 }
```

And I cannot find the correct way to modify the node.js return function:

```
if err
    console.log "Error: #{err.message}"
    throw err
res.send results
```

So I think that I only need to "wrap" the results of the query...
Any ideas?

Oh, Im using Express if it helps...

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
res.send {data: results}
```

Comment: Or client-side, if it can be modified before Ember gets hold of it: `results = {data : results};`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Since I don't know ember, I don't know where (or whether) you could place that :-)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know Ember either (hence the "if" in my comment). +1 by the way.

Comment: You can create a JSON object and store your data as @nnnnnn said.. may be like,
`var myData = {};
myData.data  = results;`